# Build Cordova tools Visual Studio 2013 CTP3.1 on Jenkins

Tags: cordova, msbuild, visual-studio-cordova

after a long struggle, I was abble to run the Build of the .jsproj from the command line, but still the project source is not being copied, but rather just blank platforms directory inside of bld\Ripple\Android\Debug.

The bld\Debug directory looks already exactly the same as the one being generated from inside VS.

I´ve used an MSBuild (through NANT) to accomplish it passing following parameters:

```
  <target name="generatedeployfolderripple">
    <exec program="${MSBuildPath}" verbose="true">
      <arg line='"${SolutionFile}"' />
      <arg value="/target:Build" />
      <arg value="/property:LangName=en-US" />
      <arg value="/v:Detailed" />
      <arg value="/property:platform=Android" />
      <arg value="/property:DebuggerFlavor=RippleNexus" />
      <arg value="/property:ProjectDir=." />
      <arg value="/property:MdaVsCliProjectDir=." />
      <arg value="/property:NpmInstallDir=${NpmInstallDir}" />
      <arg line="/property:Configuration=Debug;MDAVsixDir=${MDAVsixDir};NodeJsDir=${NodeJsDir}" />
    </exec>
  </target>
```

is there a way to generate the same project packaging as the one Visual studio generates through the command line?

My goal would be to copy the output directoru to perform a continuous integration build.

It seems that I´m missing some simple thing...

I found this, but it states clearly that it doesn´t apply to 2013, but rather just to 2015:
https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tutorial-team-build

[image: Ripple Strucutre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ripple specifically in VS 2013, there is not a built in way to accomplish this without also building for the native Android platform. Ripple was not designed for use in a CI scenario.

Instead:

1. Do a native build for Android
2. Go into bld/Debug
3. Execute ripple from the command line after installing it:

   ```
   npm install -g ripple-emulator
   ripple emulate android
   ```

In VS 2015, you don't even need to build. Instructions on converting your VS 2013 project to VS 2015 [can be found here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md). To run your project in Ripple outside of VS in 2015, first execute the following commands to install the right tools:

```
npm install -g ripple-emulator
npm install -g cordova@5.1.1
```

...replacing 5.1.1 with your target Cordova version.

Next, just check out the source code to a folder and execute the following from the root of the project folder

```
cordova platform add android
ripple emulate android
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 is far easier to get working with any build system.  There's even a [tutorial for Jenkins](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/tutorial-team-build/Jenkins.md).

That said, if you must continue to is VS 2013, you should be able to use the PowerShell Script in the ["Getting Resulting Packages to Land in the Drop Folder" section of the TFS 2013 tutorial for VS 2015 RC](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/tutorial-team-build/RC/TFS2013.md)

The instructions are fairly close to what is needed for VS 2013. The big difference as I'm sure you've noticed is the location MDAVSIXDIR is not predictable. We've resolved this in VS 2015 but we actually recommend using Gulp instead of MSBuild with projects in VS 2015 since this can run directly on OSX for your iOS build without having to pair your build server with a remote build agent. That is why the tutorials do not directly apply to VS 2013 as that technique is not available there.

Instructions on converting your VS 2013 project to VS 2015 [can be found here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md).

Comment: I plain to migrate to VS2015, that migration tutorial might help on it!

That said, I just realized that I was actually able to build it for Android already. 

Would that PowerShellScript you mentioned copy also the src resources (my html,js,css) to the Ripple Build folder? 

I´ve seen that already yesterday, but from the documentation there I tot it would copy only apk, .ipa, or .plist files, which is not what I´m missing now.

The directory I mean is bld\Ripple\Android\Debug, which currently has only an empty platforms folder

Comment: If you are doing CI, you probably don't want the Ripple folder - you likely want the actual generated apps, do you not?  Unfortunately the defaults go to Ripple.  That same tutorial tells you how to resolve that issue.  Just add the following to your MSBuild command line call: /p:DebuggerFlavor=AndroidDevice

Comment: I´d like both, as I would like to keep an updated simulator deployed as well.

But I agree with you that the real devices are actually the most important thing.

I´ve already configured a nodeJS instance to serve the emulated environment.

As for the DebuggerFlavor, yes, I´ve set another task that runs it like this and generates the Android Build!

So, my issue is only with Ripple "deployable" at this point (haven´t tried IOS so far)

Comment: In other words, when I build using VS the folder bld\Ripple\Android\Debug has all a full setup structure and not only an empty platforms.

Couldn´t figure out the diff between the VS build and the command line build

Comment: Ah!  Interesting use case. Out of curiosity, why are you deploying Ripple? Beta testing for users?  That said, is the issue that you seeing contents in bld\Ripple\Android\Debug but that the platforms folder in that location is empty?  If so, that shouldn't cause an issue.  You can npm install ripple-emulator and then run "ripple emulate" from inside the Debug folder to start it up.  Ripple itself uses no native code.

Comment: Internal QA mostly.

No, only platforms folder is there, but it´s empty.

No other folders were copied, altough the build was successful.

bld\Debug, gets some structure generated though, but not exactly the one that I´d need to push to ripple

Comment: Okay - I checked with the devs and unfortunately there's no good way to do this from MSBuild.  This scenario was not factored into the design.  In VS 2015, however, you don't even need to build.  I'll add a second answer related to this one.

Comment: Added new solution - You should be able to do a native build for VS 2013 and use Ripple.  VS 2015 you don't even need to do that.

Comment: Thanks!

Will test it

Comment: @ChuckLantz link you pointed is depreciated and new link is showing 404 error